# Replace All innerhtml text with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying for hours and I've looked a lot of samples on StackOverflow, but I can't fix my simple script.

I grabbed DOM with jQuery

```
var color = $('#bscontainer').html();
```

and now the content of color is:

```
<img src="resources/P/Blue_BG_2Col.png" id="bg">
<img src="resources/P/Blue_Content_2Col.png" id="content">
<img src="resources/P/Blue_Title_ExchangeRate.png" id="title">
<img src="resources/P/Blue_SubTitle_2Col.png" id="subtitle">
<img src="resources/P/Blue_Disclaimer_Disclaimer.png" id="disclaimer">
```

My idea is to change all the Blue to Green, and I already try this:

```
curColor="Blue";
newColor="Green";
t=color.replace(curColor,newColor);
```

It simply doesn't works. Any ideas?

Comment: @Blazemonger A bit harsh :)

Comment: It works for me. You must be doing something wrong in code that you haven't provided, or you are expecting more from the code than the methods being used are meant to provide.

Comment: I don't understand what your trying to do here..explain better

Comment: when you say it doesn't work, what do you mean?  You've shown no code where you actually write your changes back to the file, so if you're hoping to load new images, this won't do anything.  This will just give you some HTML with scripts pointing to the green resources.  You haven't done anything with it yet.

Comment: i tried to alert(t)... it still display the 'Blue' content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically you want to find each image in your `color` element and replace `Blue` with `Green` in the `src` attribute -- This is one way you can do it:

```
var color = $('#bscontainer');
color.find('img').each(function(){

    curColor="Blue";
    newColor="Green";
    this.src = this.src.replace(curColor,newColor);

});
```

No need for the `.html()` part of your code...

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question directly, replace in javascript when it takes a string parameter as the needle, only replaces the first instance. To replace all instances within a string, use a global regular expression:

```
str.replace(/Blue/g, 'Green');
```

You really ought to just modify the `src` attributes of the `img` tags though. That is the more proper way to attack this. Changing the html like you are trying to will lose any events or data bound to the DOM elements.

Comment: the problem is Blue and Green actually a variable... for example, var curColor="Blue"; var newColor="Green";

i can't make the regex works, when i use variables

Comment: @user2121401 You can if you construct a [regexp object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15146302/replace-all-innerhtml-text-with-javascript/15146398#15146398).

Answer (score 0):

[Use a callback function](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2) to actually update the HTML, and use a [regular expression (object)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to replace all instances at once:

```
$('#bscontainer').html(function (i, str) {
    curColor = new RegExp("Blue","g"); // global replace
    newColor = "Green";
    return str.replace(curColor, newColor);
});
```